# React native, "this" keyword is undefied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

so I wanted to use `this.props.navigation.navigate()` and I got an error message saying undefined.
after reading here in stockOverflow I saw that I needed declare a constructor like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    }
```

however this keeps giving me an error saying ";" is was expected regardless of what I do, here is a simplified version of my code

```
const activityStyles = ActivitiesStyles.createStyles()
export default (props) => {
    const {item: event, sensorID, homeInfo} = props

  return (
<View style={activityStyles.linkContent} underlayColor={Colors.navigationBkgdActive}>
    <View style={{flex: 0.60, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={(event)=>{this.props.navigation.navigate("WalkThru")}}>
            <SensorIcon style={iconStyle} size={Typography.bodyLineHeight} type={event.type} />
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TextInput
            placeholder={event.type}
            autoCapitalize={true}
            style={activityStyles.text}>
        </TextInput>
    </View>
</View>
 )

}
```

Comment: You forgot to end the `<TextInput` opening tag with `>`. Same for `TouchableHighlight`

Comment: There's no valid `this` in a function component. Just use the `props` that you're receiving as a parameter.

Comment: Emile Bergeron can you explain please

Comment: It means exactly that—there’s no “this”, nor do you need one. “props” is a parameter, not an instance property.

Comment: just remove `this.` and keep the following `props.navigation.navigate("WalkThru")`, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

As Emile Bergeron suggested, you should go with props since *this* keyword is available only for Class-Based components.

A class based component would be as follows.

```
export default class componentName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
          <View style={activityStyles.linkContent} underlayColor={Colors.navigationBkgdActive}>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={(event)=>{this.props.navigation.navigate("WalkThru")}}>
              <SensorIcon style={iconStyle} size={Typography.bodyLineHeight} type={event.type} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
              <TextInput
                placeholder={event.type}
              </TextInput>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }
}
```

Furthermore, I can propose you look into differences between Stateless Functional Components and Class Components in React / React-Native.

Comment: I will definitely look into that, but this did not work actually ```export default (props) => {``` is what works because I have some other values that use props after that